# How to decode the HTTP request header of chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, sockets, encoding, server

I am using python and sockets to make a simple server. When i recieve the header using `request.recv(1024)`, i can't decode the encoded data. This works fine with the Firefox. I used 'utf-8' as the codec to decode.

Do chrome uses different encoding or what?
The Error is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    head.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8: invalid`

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are exactly doing (no code shown) but a HTTP message is not UTF-8 in the first place. To cite [from the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3):

> A recipient MUST parse an HTTP message as a sequence of octets in an
> encoding that is a **superset of US-ASCII** [USASCII].  Parsing an HTTP
> message as a stream of Unicode characters, without regard for the
> specific encoding, creates security vulnerabilities due to the
> varying ways that string processing libraries handle invalid
> multibyte character sequences that contain the octet LF (%x0A).

And [later it says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) regarding the value of the fields in the HTTP header:

> Historically, **HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset** [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD **treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data**.

Thus, don't use UTF-8 to decode the HTTP message in the first place since it is not intended to be interpreted as such.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8: invalid

`\0xfc` is `ü` when interpreted as ISO-8859-1 which is probably the interpretation intended by the sender. It is not valid UTF-8 but as I said the HTTP message should not be treated as UTF-8 in the first place.